# Using Spring RestTemplate to POST params with objects

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to send a POST request using Spring's RestTemplate functionality but am having an issue sending an object.  Here is the code I am using to send the request:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

MultiValueMap<String,Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();
parameters.add("username", usernameObj);
parameters.add("password", passwordObj);

MyReturnObj ret = rt.postForObject(endpoint, parameters, MyRequestObj.class);
```

I also have a logging interceptor so I can debug the input parameters and they are *almost* correct!  Currently, the `usernameObj` and `passwordObj` parameters appear as such:

```
{"username":[{"testuser"}],"password":[{"testpassword"}]}
```

What I *want* them to look like is the following:

```
username={"testuser"},password={"testpassword"}
```

Assume that `usernameObj` and `passwordObj` are Java objects that have been marshalled into JSON.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so I ended up figuring this out, for the most part.  I ended up just writing a marshaller/unmarshaller so I could handle it at a much more fine grained level.  Here was my solution:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

// Create a multimap to hold the named parameters
MultiValueMap<String,String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String>();
parameters.add("username", marshalRequest(usernameObj));
parameters.add("password", marshalRequest(passwordObj));

// Create the http entity for the request
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>> entity =
            new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(parameters, headers);

// Get the response as a string
String response = rt.postForObject(endpoint, entity, String.class);

// Unmarshal the response back to the expected object
MyReturnObj obj = (MyReturnObj) unmarshalResponse(response);
```

This solution has allowed me to control how the object is marshalled/unmarshalled and simply posts strings instead of allowing Spring to handle the object directly.  Its helped immensely!

Comment: where is the marshalrequest source ?

Comment: It's better to put unmarshalResponse code here and complete your answer!

Answer (score 1):

**For Client Side**

To pass the object as json string, use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

**For Server Side** spring configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've tried that with no luck.  As you can see, the request is being sent as JSON but is enclosed within a JSON object with a name equal to that of the parameter name.  I don't want my JSON string to be enclosed like that.